# how do you handle token value data type in database?

Tags: wallets, exchanges, database, data-types, bignumber

Ones who do exchange / Investment platforms development, all ERC20 tokens has its atomic unit and only moved by specifying value in its atomic form.

for eg: `1 BuritoToken` with unit decimals as 18, to move `63.33 BuritoToken` we need to place `63,331,344,345,123,500,000` atomic units in tx params as hex string. it's convenient to keep it as number type in db to say sum a list of records. But we run out of column size to keep it as numbers.

Solution here seems to be to store values as hex strings in db. I wonder if thats the approach to go with.

ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL to store ETH values and token values in NUMERIC field type and I have not had any problems with overflows. It is practically unlimited since it allows 130,000 digits , I think you can sum all the blockchain volume ever transferred without any problem in such a large number. Maybe you should switch to a more powerful database.